# why does VBA valilation with large list crashed after reopening the file?

Tags: string, vba, list, validation, size

The code here worked fine as I expected. It creates the dropdown list from the string with 257 character, 88 items separated by comma. However, After I saved the file, I cannot reopen it successully. The code ( located in the excel object sheet, not module)  is lost as well. I really appreciate your input.

Changing 88 to 87, everything works normally.

```
Sub test_function()
Dim myList As String
myList = "" 

For a = 0 To 88
    myList = myList & CStr(a) & ","
Next a

'for debug
MsgBox Len(myList) & ":" & myList

ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("DC_setup").Range("A1:A10").Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=myList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a known issue/bug. Data validation list entry with >255 chars causes crash and then repair when opened.

Answer (score 0):

Your data validation list "formula" is too long.

You can make it very, very short - by using a *name* instead of a comma-separated list of values:

1. Add a new sheet to your workbook, type "Values" in cell A1
2. Add all the legal values in column A, starting at row 2
3. Select "Format as table" from the "Home" Ribbon; when prompted, make sure the table includes all the cells in column A that have a value, plus the header ("my table has headers" checkbox should be checked).
4. From the "Table tools" Ribbon, change the name of the table, e.g. `tblLegalValues`.
5. From the "Formulas" Ribbon, bring up the *Name Manager* and click the "New" button.
6. Define a workbook-scoped name - call it e.g. `legalValues`, referring to `=tblLegalValues[Values]`
7. Make your data validation list `=legalValues`
8. (optional) hide the worksheet

Now not only you get all the values you need without any issues, if you add or remove values from the `tblLegalValues` table, your data validation is automatically updated!

---

If your data validation list is really just integers between 0 and 88, then you don't need any list; change the validation type to `xlValidateWholeNumber`, keeping the `xlBetween` operator, and making `Formula1=0` and `Formula2=88`.